# How to read txt file from URL and use as string?

Tags: android, http, url

How can I read txt file content from server and use it in android? New to android!
Here is my code.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.widget.VideoView;
    /**
     * Created by Mukesh on 4/23/2017.
     */

    public class PlayerActivity extends Activity {
        private String urlStream;
        private VideoView myVideoView;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/file.txt");
                InputStream is = url.openStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(line);

                br.close();
                is.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
            myVideoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            myVideoView.setMediaController(mc);


urlStream = "";  //how to keep the text read from txt file from server


 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlStream));
                    myVideoView.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here  urlStream = text read from url. Checked  the solution everywhere but could not fix it. It is a m3u8 player android app. The m3u8 url is kept in txt file in server and the app should read url from txt file and attach it to the urlStream in app.

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution

```
private String getTextFromUrl(){
    String link="http://.../file.txt";
    ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);  
        conn.connect(); 

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;

        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                al.add(line);
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return al.get(0).toString();
}
```

then put the text int to TextView

```
t.setText(getTextFromUrl());
```

Comment: I dont want to display text in textview. I want to set text read from url to urlStream = text read from url or display text as Toast